# iPhone - Strange behaviour when '&' is included in HTTP request body

Tags: iphone, xml, http-post, nsurlconnection

I've got a very strange problem related to sending POST request from my iPhone app.

The app needs to send the HTTP post data to a third-party service.  Request is XML and it'll get XML response.  Here's my code for sending the request:

```
-(void)sendRequest:(NSString *)aRequest
{
    //aRequest parameter contains the XML string to send.
    //this string is already entity-encoded
    isDataRequest = NO;
    //the following line will created string REQUEST=<myxml>
    NSString *httpBody =  [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@=%@",requestString,aRequest];
    //I'm not sure what this next string is doing, frankly, as I didn't write this code initially
    httpBody = [(NSString*)CFURLCreateStringByAddingPercentEscapes(kCFAllocatorDefault, (CFStringRef)httpBody, NULL, CFSTR("+"), kCFStringEncodingUTF8) autorelease];   
    NSData *aData = [httpBody dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] initWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:kOOURLRequest]] autorelease]; 
    [request setHTTPBody:aData];
    [request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
    self.feedURLConnection = [[[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:request delegate:self] autorelease];
}
```

This works perfectly well as long as the request XML doesn't contain `&` symbol, for example, this XML request:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<request type="search" group="0" language="en" version="2.5.2">
    <auth>
        <serial>623E1579-AC18-571B-9022-3659764542E7</serial>
    </auth>
    <data>
        <location>
            <lattitude>51.528536</lattitude>
            <longtitude>-0.108865</longtitude>
        </location>
        <search>archive</search>
    </data>
</request>
```

is sent as expected and the correct response is received as expected.

However, when the request contains `&` character (specifically in the "search" element) - like so:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<request type="search" group="0" language="en" version="2.5.2">
    <auth>
        <serial>623E1579-AC18-571B-9022-3659764542E7</serial>
    </auth>
    <data>
        <location>
            <lattitude>51.528536</lattitude>
            <longtitude>-0.108865</longtitude>
        </location>
        <search>&amp; archive</search>
    </data>
</request>
```

Only everything up to the `&` character is sent to the server.  The server doesn't seem to receive anything beyond this character.  Note that I have a pretty much the same code working in an Android app and everything is working correctly, so it's not a problem on the server.

Any ideas how I can get this fixed would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Use a network monitor like WireShark or Charles to see what is actually being sent.

Comment: Check out the string (NSLog it) sometime between processing it and sending it. It might be getting truncated in all the processing you do on it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to Zaph's comment, I finally sorted it.  I used WireShark to see what was actually sent to the server and discovered that the request wasn't encoded completely.  In the final HTTP body the actual symbol `&` was present (part of `&amp;`).  This naturally didn't work very well on the server side, because it was receiving something like:

```
REQUEST=first_half_of_request&amp;second_half_of_request
```

When the server decoded the POST variables, `&` was taken as the separator of variables, therefore the REQUEST variable was only set to the first_half_of_request - everything up to the `&` char.

The solution was quite simple.  In line

```
httpBody = [(NSString*)CFURLCreateStringByAddingPercentEscapes(kCFAllocatorDefault, (CFStringRef)httpBody, NULL, CFSTR("+"), kCFStringEncodingUTF8) autorelease];
```

replace `CFSTR("+")` with `CFSTR("+&")` to encode `&` as well.  Now this, combined with entity encoding (`&amp;` for `&`), resulted in the correct data being sent to the server and the correct response being received.